# Unity: чтение json с android

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

К сожалению, достаточно заезженный вопрос, который у меня не работает. Делаю для своей игры переводчик по оффициальному тутору юнити, но раз у меня игра на андроид, то пришлось добавить несколько строк, тк файлы без WWW не прочесть. На всякий случай прилагаю не отрезок, а весь код:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

public class LocalizationManager : MonoBehaviour {

public static LocalizationManager instance;

private Dictionary<string, string> localizedText;
private bool isReady = false;
private string missingTextString = "Localized Text not found";

// Use this for initialization
void Awake () {
    if (instance == null)
    {
        instance = this;
    }
    else if (instance != this)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
}

public void LoadLocalizedText(string fileName)
{
    localizedText = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    string filePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "Languages/" + fileName + ".json");


    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
#if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
        WWW reader = new WWW(filePath);
        while (!reader.isDone) { }
        string dataAsJson = reader.text;
        LocalizationData loadedData = JsonUtility.FromJson<LocalizationData>(dataAsJson);

        Debug.Log("Translate is done on Android");
#endif

#if UNITY_EDITOR
        string dataAsJson = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        LocalizationData loadedData = JsonUtility.FromJson<LocalizationData>(dataAsJson);
        Debug.Log("Translate is done on Editor");
#endif

        for (int i = 0; i < loadedData.items.Length; i++)
        {
            localizedText.Add(loadedData.items[i].key, loadedData.items[i].value);
        }

        Debug.Log("Data loaded, dictionary contains: " + localizedText.Count + " entries");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Can not find file!");
    }

    isReady = true;
}

public string GetLocalizedValue(string key)
{
    string result = missingTextString;
    if (localizedText.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        result = localizedText[key];
    }

    return result;
}

public bool GetIsReady()
{
    return isReady;
}
}
```

При запуске через юнити эдитор, все работает, а при запуске с телефона-андроид пишет на всех текстовых полях "Localized Text not found". Подскажите, что не так?

Comment: `filePath` выведите в логи.

Comment: 02-10 23:00:18.439 12053-12076/? I/Unity: jar:file:///data/app/com.Desdiene.ProductName-1/base.apk!/assets/Languages/ru_RU.json
     
    (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 43)
02-10 23:00:18.441 12053-12076/? E/Unity: Can not find file!
     
    (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 43)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спустя несколько дней, как я начал сходить с ума по этой проблеме, нашлось решение. Все дело в цикле `while (!reader.isDone) { }`. Видимо, он криво выполнялся и вел к тому, что файл не читался. Прилагаю свой рабочий код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

public class LocalizationManager : MonoBehaviour {

public static LocalizationManager instance;

private Dictionary<string, string> localizedText;
private bool isReady = false;
private string missingTextString = "Localized Text not found";

// Use this for initialization
void Awake () {
    if (instance == null)
    {
        instance = this;
    }
    else if (instance != this)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
}

public void LoadLocalizedText(string fileName)
{
    localizedText = new Dictionary<string, string>();


    string filePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "Languages/" + fileName + ".json");

    Debug.Log(filePath);
    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        string dataAsJson = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        LocalizationData loadedData = JsonUtility.FromJson<LocalizationData>(dataAsJson);
        Debug.Log("Translate is done on Editor");


        for (int i = 0; i < loadedData.items.Length; i++)
        {
            localizedText.Add(loadedData.items[i].key, loadedData.items[i].value);
        }

        Debug.Log("Data loaded, dictionary contains: " + localizedText.Count + " entries");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Can not find file!");
    }

    isReady = true;
}


IEnumerator LoadLocalizedTextOnAndroid(string fileName)
{
    localizedText = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    string filePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, fileName + ".json");
    WWW reader = new WWW(filePath);
    yield return reader;
    Debug.LogWarning(filePath);
    if (reader.error != null)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning(reader.error);
        yield break;
    } 

    string dataAsJson = reader.text;

    LocalizationData loadedData = JsonUtility.FromJson<LocalizationData>(dataAsJson);
    Debug.Log("Translate is done on Android");

    for (int i = 0; i < loadedData.items.Length; i++)
    {
        localizedText.Add(loadedData.items[i].key, loadedData.items[i].value);
        Debug.Log("KEYS:" + loadedData.items[i].key);
    }

    isReady = true;
}


public void SetLanguage(string fileName)
{
    if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.WindowsEditor)
        LoadLocalizedText(fileName);
    else if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.OSXEditor)
        LoadLocalizedText(fileName);
    else if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
        StartCoroutine("LoadLocalizedTextOnAndroid", fileName);
}


public string GetLocalizedValue(string key)
{
    string result = missingTextString;
    if (localizedText.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        result = localizedText[key];
    }

    return result;
}

public bool GetIsReady()
{
    return isReady;
}
}
```